# Prove that there are $736$ $2 \times 2$ matrices ($A$) where $A=A^{-1}$

Tags: matrices, discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, cryptography

I'm doing some assignments to teach myself cryptology. I am still at the introductory cryptology level, where a lot of it is discrete mathematics, so I believe - and hope - that it is a somewhat simple question for someone in here. It has shown to not be that for me, as it has been holding me prisoner the whole evening and afternoon.

**The assignment that is bugging me, contains the following text:**

Let A be an invertible $m \times m$ matrix over $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$, where $A=A^{-1}$ and from which it follows that $det(A) \equiv \pm 1$ mod $26$.

Show that there are $736$ $2 \times 2$ matrices $A$ over $\mathbb{Z}_{26}$ for which it holds that $A=A^{-1}$.

Hint: Split the problem into two cases. Consider the problem first modulo $2$, then modulo $13$, and finally use the Chinese Remainder Theorem to get the result modulo $26$.

**What I have tried to do:**

A lot that have not yielded any results yet... The point where I am at now, is after I have split $det(A) \equiv \pm 1$ mod 26 into: $det(A) \equiv \pm 1$ mod $13$ and $det(A) \equiv \pm 1$ mod $2$.

Afterwards, I have been thinking that since $A=A^{-1}$ means that $A^2=I$, what I need to do is find all cases where:

$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}^2=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$

Which means I have the congruences:
\begin{align}
a^2+bc&\equiv1\\
ab+bd&\equiv0\\
ca+dc&\equiv0\\
cb+d^2&\equiv1\
\end{align}

I have no clue where to go from here though.... Or if what I have been doing so far, is the correct way of doing it, if I want to follow that hint... I hope someone can and will help out, and are willing to shed some light on this.

Thanks (a lot) in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of http://math.stackexchange.com/q/324542/264

Comment: Jonas, welcome to math.SE. I wanted to express my appreciation for explaining everything you've tried, **and** for formatting your question so nicely - many people don't take the time to - and I hope you continue to participate here. However, since this question has already been asked, and we prefer to keep all related discussion in one place, this question is going to be closed as a duplicate; just wanted to reassure you that you didn't do anything wrong.

Comment: Ah, thanks for the warm welcome words :) And thanks for linking that other article. Seems I didn't search well enough though, before writing my question. If I have any questions, I'll direct them to that article instead. :)

Comment: @JonasSmith Actually if you have an issue with the answers there, you should open a new question with that and the other things you don't understand because no one really looks at old questions, especially answered ones.